# determine which files received (multiple uploading files zendframwork)

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have a problem with uploading multiple files with php zend framework

i have a form which contains many input[type="file"] tags, each tag has its unique name and id attributes.

when receiving this data, all files gathering in an array files, i can receive and store it easily now, but the problem here is how can i identify which file coming from which input element? it is very important to me to know that because each specific file will store in a specific field in my database.

here an example

```
<input type "file" name = "main_photo"/>
<input type "file" name = "horizontal_plan"/>


$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$files = $upload->getFileInfo();
foreach ($files as $file => $info)
{
if($upload->isValid($file))
{
//here how can i point to the main_photo file or the horizontal_plan file?
}
}
```

please help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see them as below:

PHP print $_FILES

```
Array
(
    [s1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [s2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)

<!--HTML FORM-->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="t23.php">
    <input type="file" name="s1">
    <input type="file" name="s2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

As you see, the html file variables, s1 & s2 become an array with their own set of data in PHP....should be easy for you to determine that each array corresponds to its namsake variable in html. :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you Pushpesh, but i tried it but when i print file["filename"] it prints no thing.

Comment: see if this helps you - http://ahsangill.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/zend-framework-file-upload-using-zend_form_element_file/

Comment: unfortunately i have been using a similar code for uploading but i am still can not solve the problem, thank you for help at all.